# Detect view has update frame successfully

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an `UIButton` in an `UIView` and I have set the the constraint width for `UIButton` programmatically inside `(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {` using  `PureLayout` like

```
self.errorButtonConstraintWidth = [self.btnError autoSetDimension:ALDimensionWidth toSize:5];
self.errorButtonConstraintWidth.constant = 40;
NSLog(@"afterChangeContraintWith = %f",self.btnError.frame.size.width);
```

But after set the constraint with, the `Log` for print button frame always print 0. I think after I change the constraint with the frame not update immediately.
How can I detect when my view has updated successfully?

The reason why I want to detect when my view has updated successfully because, I want to display a dropdownlist at center-horizontal and below this `UIButton` after I change button width to 40

Comment: Where do you call this code? `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear:`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: @Larme I'm using it in init method of  `UIView`

Comment: It didn't apply the layout yet I guess.

Comment: @Larme can you explain more, I am new in iOS

Comment: if you do it in will viewDidAppear  then you can get frame correctly , and call layoutIfNeeded after set constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame will not be set immediately, it will be set in the next layouting process.

but you can do this

### Approach 1

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // in this method, the frame has been set.
}
```

### Approach 2

```
// This will force autolayout to determine the frame
// without waiting for the next layouting schedule
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```